# pass argument to gnuplot configuration file

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot configuration file qe.conf

```
#qe.conf
reset
set terminal png truecolor
set output "qe.png"
set autoscale
set style data lines
plot "qe.txt" using 1:2 title "%Red", '' using 1:3 title "%G-r", '' using 1:4 title "%G-b", '' using 1:5 title "%R"
set output
```

I am calling this from a shell script. I would like to pass variables to this configuration file. Can anyone suggest how can I do that?

I tried 1 thing.
I have the datafile in the variable $source. So I tried the following command in the shell script

```
gnuplot -e "filename=$source" qe.conf
```

Comment: I'm confused... Your gnuplot script (`qe.conf`) never attempts to _use_ the variable `filename`.  I think that the variable should be set properly (IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

The `-e` option tells gnuplot that you are passing commands directly. But `qe.conf` is not a  gnuplot command and also is outside the double quotes.

This does the job (tested):

<s>gnuplot -e "filename=$source; load('qe.conf')"</s>

```
gnuplot -e "filename='$source'; load('qe.conf')"
```

Comment: That should give problems since `$source` is expected to be a string. And the way of loading a gnuplot script is fine as done by the OP, no need to use `load` although it doesn't harm. The line should be `gnuplot -e "filename='$source'" qe.conf`. And in any case, as note by mgilson, this has only an effect if `filename` is also used inside the script.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The code worked for me because I played with an integer... I just changed it.

Comment: My qe.conf

`#qe.conf
print filename`

Shell script
`#!/bin/bash
source="file1.txt"
gnuplot -e "filename='$source'; load('qe.conf')"`

I get the error as 

"Cannot open load file '-e'
line 0: util.c: No such file or directory"